# React Component : Reassign a props value

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've created a custom component :

```
      <Button
        randomProps="asdasds"
        primary
        className="m-2"
      />
      <Button
        label="secondary"
        secondary
      />
```

Now, in my Buutton.js I want to set the value of label to be the one from randomProps (if randomProps are define of course).
So, I did something like this :

```
const Button = ({ label, randomProps }) => {  
    if (randomProps) label = randomProps;
    return (
    <FlatButton
      label={label}     
    />
  );
}
```

But, I've got a ES6 error : Assignment to function parameter 'label' : no-param-reassign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not assign any value to a prop that you receive. Avoid doing something like `label = randomProps`.

You could create another variable, or use the value directly as a ternary operator:

```
const Button = ({ label, randomProps }) => {
    return (
    <FlatButton
      label={randomProps? randomProps: label }
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes, I like your Idea but now I've got : " uncessary use of conditional expression for default assignement (no-unneedeed-ternary)" So I suppose label={randomProps || label} is better

Comment: indeed. Checked here https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unneeded-ternary  and as you are returning the same attribute that you are testing, it is equivalent to `randomProps || label`